# For the purpose of this project, I can only use WebClient to stream the document using a multi part form. The server is expecting a part = File

Tags: c#, http

As I couldn't use either `HttpClient` nor `WebRequest`, I used `WebClient`, but first I needed to build the multi part form,
Specified the file field name and filename
converted the document to bytes
Created a method to combine arrays
When I try posting it, I get server response code "400" (Request part "File" is not present

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    //Declare Credentials

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {


            // Create the boundary for the multipart form data
            string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

            // Set the content type for the request
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

            // Create the multipart form data
            byte[] boundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
            byte[] trailerBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

            // Specify the file field name and filename
            string fileField = "File";
            string fileName = "document.pdf"; 



            // Build the multipart form data
            byte[] requestBytes = new byte[0];
            requestBytes = CombineBytes(requestBytes, boundaryBytes);
            requestBytes = CombineBytes(requestBytes, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Content-Disposition: form-data; name={fileField}; filename={fileName}\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"));
            requestBytes = CombineBytes(requestBytes, fileBytes);
            requestBytes = CombineBytes(requestBytes, trailerBytes);

            // Upload the multipart form data
            byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadData(apiUrl, "POST", requestBytes);

            // Handle the response here
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: _"As I couldn't use either HttpClient nor WebRequest"_ - **why not?** (Internally, `WebClient` uses `HttpWebRequest`), so you'd better have a _good_ excuse...

Comment: Does CombineBytes actually work? So does requestBytes actually contain something when you call UploadData?

Comment: The CombineBytes work. I tested these by streaming the document to a local machine @Ralf

Comment: Then the format seems to be the problem. I'm not to familiar with "multipart/form-data" but i suspect you need to a certain degree encode the filebytes (we don't see how they are created). So maybe by giving the Mimepart a Transfer-Encoding and encoding the filebytes accordingly. As i said im not to familiar with the format but the pure bytes may contain the "\r\n" bytes and this should breaks if not encoded properly.